# Profiling Nodejs V0.12

Tags: node.js, profiling

How to profile a nodejs script with sockJs + Express implementation.

I tried Heapdump, but it always empty. Below is the code for same.

```
var heapdump = require('heapdump');

process.once('SIGINT', function () {
    console.log('Closed');
    heapdump.writeSnapshot();
});
```

My current verions of nodejs is V0.12, sockJs is 0.3.12.

Comment: Is the event actually fired? You are using a very specific signal to listen for (`SIGINT`) but perhaps your application exited for a different reason. Have you tried listening for the `exit` event?

Comment: @RobertRossmann I tried to fire it manually and check, but the snapshot is always empty for some reason.